# Every regular and second countable space is a $G_\delta$ space, without assuming Urysohn’s metrization theorem

Tags: general-topology

In the Wikipedia article about [$G_\delta$ spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_space), it is mentioned that : "without assuming Urysohn’s metrization theorem, one can prove that every regular space with a countable base is a $G_\delta$ space."

The proof should not be very difficult, still I don't know how to prove it. I'm curious about the proof.

Minor remark :

> Urysohn's metrization theorem states that every **Hausdorff**
>   second-countable regular space is metrizable. And $X$ is metrizable
>   $\Rightarrow$ $X$ is a $G_\delta$ space. But in the aforementioned statement of the
>   Wikipedia article on $G_\delta$ spaces, it is not assumed that $X$ is Hausdorff. So even
>   the use of "Urysohn's metrization theorem" seems compromised in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be regular and second countable, and let $F$ be a closed set in $X$. Let $\mathscr{B}$ be a countable base for $X$. For each $x\in X\setminus F$ there are disjoint open sets $U_x$ and $V_x$ such that $x\in U_x$ and $F\subseteq V_x$. Let $B_x\in\mathscr{B}$ be such that $x\in B_x\subseteq U_x$; then $F\cap\operatorname{cl}B_x=\varnothing$, so $F\subseteq X\setminus\operatorname{cl}B_x$. Let $\mathscr{W}=\{X\setminus\operatorname{cl}B_x:x\in X\setminus F\}$; then $\mathscr{W}$ is a countable family of open sets, and $F=\bigcap\mathscr{W}$.